# How to calculate the distance between a Vector3 and a (3D polygon triangle)?

Tags: 3d

How to calculate the distance between a Vector3 and a (3D polygon triangle)?

for example : " float DistanceToTrianale( Vector3 pos, Vector3 Edges1, Vector3 Edges2, Vector3 Edges3)

thanks in advance

Comment: Distance to where? The center of the triangle?

Comment: I say this not having easy access to it where I'm at right now, but have a copy of http://realtimecollisiondetection.net/books/rtcd/ on hand or you're doing life wrong.  The answer boils down to using Voronoi regions and easy math, all explained in detail in that book.

Comment: bummzack - the Distance the nearest point in the triangle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a nice guide to the problem, with implementation:

http://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/DistancePoint3Triangle3.pdf